# How to pass arguments to a java api from html code using play framework?

Tags: java, html, playframework

I want to pass arguments from HTML view to Java API in play framework.
I've written the following code. What changes should be done to successfully pass the arguments from Html view to API in java controller?.

When i tried passing it as @w.username and @w.email or by keeping '@w.username' or @w.username i've got error.

```
@import model.User 
@(users: List[User]) 
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Users</h1>

        <table>
            <thead>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for(w <- users) {
            <tr>
                <td>@w.username</td>
                <td>@w.email</td>
                <td>@w.status</td>
                <td>            
                    <form action="@routes.UserController.getUser(w.username,w.email)">
                        <input type = "submit" value="View Deatils">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It must work just like you wrote it:

```
@routes.UserController.getUser(w.username,w.email)
```

Comment: Thank you, It hasn't worked with the form action. So I've tried anchor tag instead of action then it worked fine. There is no problem with the way I've called the method.